# Timer di not stop correctly as i wanted

Tags: vb.net, timer

So I want my Timer stop when "i" (i As Integer = 0) reach 90. But when I test it, the timer stop when "i" reach 100. Or maybe Timer was stopped when "i" is 90, but the "i" is changed to 100. How can I fix the problem?
If you confused with my explaination, heres the code

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseHover
    Form3.Show() '<<You can ignore this
    Timer2.Start() '<<You can ignore this
    Timer4.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
    Timer2.Stop() '<<You can ignore this
    Timer3.Start() '<<You can ignore this
    Timer4.Stop()
    Timer5.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    If i = "90" Then
        Timer4.Stop()
    End If
    i = i + 10
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    TextBox2.Text = i '<< I want to check the "i"
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    With e.Graphics
        .TranslateTransform(PictureBox1.Width \ 2, PictureBox1.Height \ 2)
        .RotateTransform(i)
        .DrawImage(Image.FromFile("D:\Gambar Desktop\RodMerah.png"), -(PictureBox1.Width \ 2), (-PictureBox1.Height \ 2))
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Timer5_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer5.Tick
    If i = 0 Then
        Timer5.Stop()
    End If
    i = i - 10
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just need to put `If` after I put `i = i + 10`. So from

```
Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    If i = "90" Then
        Timer4.Stop()
    End If
    i = i + 10
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    TextBox2.Text = i '<< I want to check the "i"
End Sub
```

I changed it to

```
Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    i = i + 15
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    TextBox2.Text = i '<< I want to check the "i"
    If i = "90" Then
        Timer4.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

But still works if you add `Else i = i + 10` to the second one, but nothing different.

Comment: Don't compare integers to strings!  It will cause you problems eventually.